# How to loop over directives, compiling, and attaching to DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a number of directives that I would like to compile and attach to the DOM. For example:

```
mod.controller("ctrl, ["$scope", "$compile", function($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.tools = [
        {
            title: "foo",
            directive: $compile("<foo-bar></foo-bar>")($scope)
        },
        {
            title: "qux",
            directive: $compile("<qux-bar></qux-bar>")($scope)
        }
        ...
    ];
```

Then in HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="tool in tools">
    <div class="tool">
        <h3>{{tool.title}}</h3>
        {{tool.directive}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like each directive to be compiled and injected into the DOM. But nothing happens. I expect because I am calling `$compile` too late. Is there a better way to do this?

FWIW, if I compile the directive and "manually" append it to the DOM, it works:

```
$('body').append($compile('<foo-bar></foo-bar>')($scope));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it this way; the `{{...}}` bindings do not accept elements. They *can* be made to accept HTML, but this HTML is static - uncompiled.

If you want dynamic directives, you have to do it yourself. One option is with an auxiliary directive, e.g. the `container-directive` below:

```
<div class="tool" container-directive>
  <h3>{{tool.title}}</h3>
  <placeholder style="display: none"></placeholder>
</div>
```

It takes the `tool` from its context, `$compile`s it, and replaces the dummy placeholder element. Suppose the `tools` are defined as:

```
this.tools = [
    { title: 'foo', directive: 'foo-bar' },
    { title: 'qux', directive: 'qux-bar' }
];
```

Then a very simple implementation would be:

```
app.directive('containerDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.find('placeholder')
        .replaceWith($compile('<' + scope.tool.directive + '></' + scope.tool.directive + '>')(scope));
    }
  };
});
```

See a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kxj60cbo/

This code demonstrates the general idea. It definitely will need some adjustment to fit your needs. E.g. the directive is tightly coupled with the name of the iteration variable - `tool` - maybe using isolated scope would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't inject I would just qualify what to show

```
<div ng-repeat="tool in tools">
    <div class="tool">
        <h3>{{tool.title}}</h3>
        <foo-bar ng-if="tool.title = 'foo'"></foo-bar>
        <qux-bar ng-if="tool.title = 'qux'"></qux-bar>
    </div>
</div>
```